# Can separable prefixes be considered adverbs?

Tags: adverb, separable-verb

For example, consider the sentence, “Ich springe hinein.” Is *hinein* considered to be the separable prefix of the verb *hineinspringen* or an adverb modifying the verb *springen*?

Comment: Yes, they can be considered both, and it is merely by convention that one is used more often.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely: *hinein* **is** an adverb, which may be **used** as a prefix in a compound. An adjective can also be used as a prefix, but nouns and verbs can't (at least with verbs).

The only distinction you (and me) have to learn is, that some verb-adverb pairs are so closely aligned, that both are written as one word for the infinitive form:

- *schönschreiben*, but *schön schreiben*
- *wegfliegen*, but *weg reisen*

Since the recent reforms, I always have to look that up in the Duden.

Comment: There is usually a difference in stress.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm afraid you confuse this with the rule for separable (?) verbs (whether a compound verb can be split). My focus here is, whether it is a compound at all.

Comment: And I’m saying that a compound vs. a sequence of words often differ in stress.

Comment: What @chirlu means is that *schönschreiben* is pronounced /'ʃø:n​ˌ​ʃraibən/ or related while *schön schreiben* is pronounced /​ˌ​ʃø:n'ʃraibən/ with an optional glottal stop between *schön* and *schreiben.*